# Page doesn't show up in Google searches

Tags: google, google-index, search-results

When I search on Google for "pollackstorch" I get an invitation to the administrator rather than the page itself. When I search on Bing or AltaVista I get the page itself.  How can I get Google to return the page itself like the others do?

Comment: Search on Google for what?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're already logged into Google (either via gmail, blogspot, or some other Google service), so when it returns the result to you it's taking you to the admin page, because you're the admin. If you log out of google and do the search it should take you to the public page because then you're just an anonymous user.

Comment: Good idea. I always check my SERPs with a different browser were I doesn't keep any cookies and I am not logged in with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it hasn't been indexed by Google yet, but it was indexed by Bing and Yahoo. How old is the website? Do you have inbound links to it? Did you submit it to Google?
Do a search with Google like that:

> site: `http://yourDomain.com`

If your site doesn't show up in the results page than it hasn't been indexed.

If you know to have been indexed and have disappeared, then it could be a Google penalty for breaking their TOS.

Comment: If I add .com, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en

is Google's central dashboard from where you can get control of how your page is indexed by Google. It is not a guarantee that the page will be indexed.

Moreover, you can add an XML site map to assist Google bot.